# How to Use Already created Google Managed SSL with GKE ingress or ISTIO ingress

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

I have already a google managed SSL certificate created (with dns verification option). I want to use same certificate in my istio-ingress for SSL. Is there any possible annotations available ?

We can create ManagedCertificate resource in GKE, but it is uses the loadbalancer verification option which does not support wildcard certificate.

What to do if I want to create certificate like (*.example.com) and attached it with istio-ingress or gke ingress ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the wild card certificate with the Cert-manger.

Here is my [article](https://medium.com/@harsh.manvar111/wild-card-certificate-using-cert-manager-in-kubernetes-3406b042d5a2) on requesting the **wild card** certificate with **DNS** verification as it's not supported with **HTTP**.

https://medium.com/@harsh.manvar111/wild-card-certificate-using-cert-manager-in-kubernetes-3406b042d5a2

For GCP DNS verification you can follow official guide : https://cert-manager.io/docs/configuration/acme/dns01/google/

Once auth is successful you will be able to request the certificate and it will get stored in K8s secret.

**create a service account** :

```
PROJECT_ID=myproject-id
gcloud iam service-accounts create dns01-solver --display-name "dns01-solver"
```

**Binding policy** :

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT_ID \
   --member serviceAccount:dns01-solver@$PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
   --role roles/dns.admin
```

**K8s secret** :

```
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create key.json \
   --iam-account dns01-solver@$PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com
kubectl create secret generic clouddns-dns01-solver-svc-acct \
   --from-file=key.json
```

**issuer**

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Issuer
metadata:
  name: gcp-issuer
spec:
  acme:
    ...
    solvers:
    - dns01:
        cloudDNS:
          # The ID of the GCP project
          project: $PROJECT_ID
          # This is the secret used to access the service account
          serviceAccountSecretRef:
            name: clouddns-dns01-solver-svc-acct
            key: key.json
---
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: le-crt
spec:
  secretName: tls-secret
  issuerRef: 
    kind: Issuer
    name: letsencrypt-prod
  commonName: "*.devops.example.in"
  dnsNames:
    - "*.devops.example.in"
```

You can attach this newly auto-created **secret** to **Ingress** or **Gateway** in **Istio** as per need. That **secret** will be storing your wild card **certificate**.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: gateway
  annotations:
      cert-manager.io/issuer: gcp-issuer
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      credentialName: tls-secret # This should match the Certificate secretName
    hosts:
    - *.devops.example.in
```

Comment: what to do if I don't want to use letsencrypt certificate. I have already one google Managed wildcard certificate in GCP. I want to use same google managed certificate in ingress. is there any way ?

Comment: no managed cert only possible with the GKE ingress which class GCE with that you can use the managed certificate and it will work, so either you get change to GCE ingress or nginx + gke ingress is option

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue:

1. have a wildcard certificate from Certificate Manager
2. wanted to use it for multiple k8 services for ingress with tls (in my case all services were grpc, but it doesn't matter would work the same for https)

First of all, GKE does not support Certificate Manager (at least not yet). Details [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/issues/1692)

This is a workaround that was suggested in the GitHub issue and worked for me:

1. Create a placeholder `ManagedCertificate` object:

```
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
kind: ManagedCertificate
metadata:
  labels:
    < set labels here as needed>
  name: placeholder-certificate
spec:
  domains:
  - foo.example.com
```

Ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: "placeholder-certificate"  # connecting to dummy ssl, switched via deployment scripts to wildcard ssl
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: some-service
      port:
        number: XXXX
```

This will make GKE setup target https proxy, which can be updated to point to a certificate map of your certificate:

1. `kubectl describe ingress XXXX` (you will need to wait for it become available, takes little time for everything to launch)
2. find the annotation for `ingress.kubernetes.io/https-target-proxy`
3. update the target proxy:

```
gcloud compute target-https-proxies update <target proxy> --certificate-map=<map name>
```